# Class Variable Retrieval in Python

Tags: python, class, textbox, tkinter, ttk

This is a GUI I’ve been writing for a script I already have working. What I’m struggling with here is retrieving the information in the textboxes.

Under the definition `generate` I am able to pop a name off of `listx` but I am unable to grab the local variable `entry` from any of the instances of the `new_title_box` class.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
boxvar=""
folder=""
listx=[]
count = 1
myrow = 1

class new_title_box:
    def __init__(self,name):
        global myrow, count, listx
        self.entry = StringVar()
        self.name = name
        self.name = ttk.Entry(mainframe,width=45,textvariable=self.entry)
        self.name.grid(column=1,row=myrow+1,sticky=(N,W))
        listx.append(name)
        print(listx) ## For debugging to insure that it is working correctly, if it gives output it, this part works
        myrow = myrow + 1
        count=count+1

def make_new(*args):
    new_title_box('box'+str(count))

def generate(*args):
    global listx, boxvar
    while len(listx) > 0:
        boxvar=listx.pop(0)
        print(boxvar) ## For debugging to insure that it is working correctly, if it gives output it, this part works
        folder = boxvar.entry.get() ## Not working here
        print(folder) ## For debugging to insure that it is working correctly, if it gives output it, this part works

root = Tk()
root.title("File Maker")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding = "50 50 50 50")
mainframe.grid(column = 0,row = 0,sticky = (N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
mainframe.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

add_entry = ttk.Button(mainframe,width=20, text = "add entry", command=make_new)
add_entry.grid(column=2,row=2,sticky=(N,W))
add_entry = ttk.Button(mainframe,width=20, text = "make files", command=generate)
add_entry.grid(column=2,row=3,sticky=(N,W))

root.mainloop()
```

Here's the traceback I'm getting:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1442, in call 
    return self.func(*args) 
  File "C:\python\SampAqTkinter.py", line 28, in generate 
    folder = boxvar.entry ## Not working here 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'entry'
```

Comment: `boxvar.entry` should work just fine. What is the error message or other symptom of it "not working?"

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1442, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\python\SampAqTkinter.py", line 28, in generate
    folder = boxvar.entry ## Not working here
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'entry'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *two* things that need to be changed to fix the problem you describe:

1. In the `new_title_box.__init__()` method change:
     `listx.append(name)` to
     `listx.append(self.name)`
2. In the `generate()` function, change:
     `folder = boxvar.entry.get()` to
     `folder = boxvar.get()`.

Comment: Awesome. That worked perfectly. As you can probably see I'm a bit new to using classes (this is first time I have used one successfully). I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Yeah...it can take while to get the hang of using classes and the whole object-oriented programming thing -- unfortunately using `Tkinter` isn't the best thing to be learning it through because a lot if it seems somewhat arbitrary, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending a string to listx, use `self.name` instead of the local string `name`